Trying to make a OneToMany relationship in GraphQL
I'm new to GraphQL, and i am trying to create a OneToMany relationship between movies and their subtitles in different languages. Here is my code:
(i setup the foreign key in the DB tables)
This is my schema file
type Movie {
    movieId: ID!
    englishName: String!
    subtitles: [Subtitle]!
}

type Subtitle {
    subtitleId: ID!
    movieId: Movie!
    locale: String!
    ...
}

Java entities:
@Entity
@Table(name="movie")
public class Movie {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="movie_id")
    private Long movieId;
    
    @Column(name="english_name")
    private String englishName;
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="movie", cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval=true)
    private Set<Subtitle> subtitles;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="subtitle")
public class Subtitle {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="subtitle_id")
    private Long subtitleId;
    
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false)
    private Movie movie;
    
    @Column(name="locale")
    private String locale;
    ...
}

Resolver
@Slf4j
@Component
public class SubtitleResolver implements GraphQLQueryResolver {

    @Autowired
    private SubtitleDAO subtitleDAO;
    
    public Set<Subtitle> getAllSubtitles(String locale) {
        log.info("Getting all subtitles for locale {}", locale);
        return subtitleDAO.getAllSubtitlesForLocale(locale);
    }
}

But when i try to run this, i get two errors

in the Subtitle class, it is asking me to put in getters for the attributes of the Movie class.
And when i add these getters, i get this error :


SchemaClassScannerError: Two different classes used for type Movie:
return type of method public java.util.Set
com.home.moviesubtitles.dao.MovieResolver.getAllSubtitlesForLocale

class com.home.moviesubtitles.entities.Movie: |   return type of method public com.home.moviesubtitles.entities.Movie
com.home.moviesubtitles.entities.Subtitle.getMovie()


Does anyone know why this is happening ?
